# Django model unique constraint based on existing model data?

Tags: python, django, django-models, constraints

Is it possible to make reference to existing model data, as part of a Django unique constraint check?

For example,

```py
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ....
    my_field = models.IntField(...)


    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.CheckConstraint(
                check=models.Q(my_field__gte=MyModel.objects.all().last().my_field,
                name="example_constraint" 
        ]
```

In this pseudocode example, I query MyModel, fetching the latest record, and use the value of it's 'my_field' property as part of the constraint, when adding a new MyModel.

---

### Update

While it appears that my pseudocode will not have the intended effect, I am now wondering if there is any possiblity to use django.db.models Max(), to achieve the desired outcome?

For example:

```py
constraints = [
    models.CheckConstraint(
        check=models.Q(my_field__gte=Max(my_field),
        name="example_constraint" 
    ]
```

Will this call to Max(my_field) return the max value of my_field, from the existing database rows? Or is it simply passing the current instance value of my_field to the Max() function?

Comment: It is generally better to avoid using existing model data as part of a unique constraint check. Instead, you can use a fixed value, a constant, or a combination of fields that uniquely identify each record. If you need to enforce a more complex constraint, you can use a custom validator or a database trigger to ensure data consistency.

Comment: I want to ensure that the record being added occurs more recently in time than previously added records. To do this requires fetching the most recently added record, and comparing against it's timestamp. A constant / fixed value is no use in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, it is possible to make a reference to existing model data as part of a Django unique constraint check, as you have demonstrated in your pseudocode example. However, it is generally not recommended to do so.
In your example, every time a new instance of MyModel is created, the query MyModel.objects.all().last() will be executed, which can be costly and slow down the application.

A better approach would be to use a custom validator to enforce the constraint, instead of relying on a query to fetch the latest record. Here is an eg
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
my_field = models.IntegerField()

```
class Meta:
    constraints = [
        models.CheckConstraint(
            check=models.Q(my_field__gte=0),
            name='my_field_positive'
        ),
    ]

def clean(self):
    super().clean()
    last_instance = MyModel.objects.order_by('-id').first()
    if last_instance and self.my_field < last_instance.my_field:
        raise ValidationError('my_field must be greater than or equal to the last instance')
```

Comment: "_In your example, every time a new instance of MyModel is created, the query MyModel.objects.all().last() will be executed_" that is actually false. Everything added in `constraints` is a database constraint. `MyModel.objects.all().last().my_field` will execute only once on server startup and will not work as OP expects. This also will have the problem of generating migrations (to update the constraint) perpetually as entries are added.

Comment: See how do I write a good answer [answer] and also do proper formatting.

Comment: A custom validator cannot be used to enforce the constraint as a validator only accepts one parameter (the value being validated). In my case, I need access to additional model fields, to perform the query that's necessary to complete the validation.

In terms of my example being costly, what's the difference whether my validation query is performed as part of the model's unique constraints, vs as part of form validation? Either way, the db is hit with an identical query...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).